# NavBar Auto Toggling On

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the `onclick` method for turning my navbar on/off the problem that I'm having is when I adjust my screen size to mobile view my nav auto turns on.

I'm not very good at JavaScript. I have just started learning it so just fiddled around and absolutely nothing worked for me. Someone told me to put aria-expanded on my HTML so also tried that:

```js
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("nav_bar").style.height = "0%";
  document.getElementById("open-btn").style.display = "inline-block";
  document.getElementById("close-btn").style.display = "none";
}

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("nav_bar").style.height = "100%";
  document.getElementById("open-btn").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("close-btn").style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

```css
  body {
  background: url(images/bg-img-01.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nav_bar {
  background: radial-gradient( ellipse at top, rgba(196, 199, 200, 0.8), rgba(250, 255, 255, 0.02) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1%);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#nav_bar>img {
  display: none;
}

.nav {
  background: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  margin-inline: auto;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  width: 65%;
  left: 20%;
  padding: 1.4em;
}

.list-item {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #CBD5DF;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.list-item {
  position: relative;
}

.list-item::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background-color: #535792;
  height: 4px;
  width: 0%;
  top: 25px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.list-item:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.list-item:hover {
  color: #C4C7C8;
}

#close-btn,
#open-btn {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  #nav_bar>img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10em;
    left: 20%;
    top: 10%;
  }
  #nav_bar {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .nav {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1.2rem;
    top: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  .list-item {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #ffdada;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  #close-btn,
  #open-btn {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #818181;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  #close-btn:hover {
    color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="nav_bar">
    <a href="#" id="close-btn">
      <i aria-expanded="false" onclick="closeNav()" class="bi bi-x-lg"></i>
    </a>
    <img src="assests/images/moon.png" alt="" />

    <div class="nav">
      <a class="list-item" href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="list-item" href="#">About Me</a>
      <a class="list-item" href="#">Projects</a>
      <a class="list-item" href="#">C.V</a>
      <a class="list-item" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a aria-expanded="false" href="#" id="open-btn" onclick="openNav()"><i class="bi bi-list"></i
    ></a>
  <script src="assests/nav.js"></script>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: 2 major issues here: First you sue an anchor that leads back to your site. As soon as you click the anchor you will reload your site. Next, you create 2 functions with different names and 2 different anchors to trigger them. Use 1 single button and sue the `classList.toggle` function to add and remove a CSS class instead.

Comment: PS: `aria-expanded` does not add the functionality you want to have. It is "merely"  an attribute for screen readers.

Comment: Yeah i just learned about aria attributes yesterday don't know why bootcamps don't cover these topics

Comment: And thanks for the info i didn't know i could use 1 function with toggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the `classList.toggle` function that adds/remove a class from the Navbar. In this example, I add or remove the class `d-none` that has the property: `display: none` in CSS. With that you can hide or show the navbar by pressing the same button with a single line of code:

```js
const BUTTON = document.querySelector('#toggle_navBar');
const NAV = document.querySelector('nav');

BUTTON.addEventListener('click', function() {
  NAV.classList.toggle('d-none');
});
```

```css
  body {
  background: url(images/bg-img-01.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background: radial-gradient( ellipse at top, rgba(196, 199, 200, 0.8), rgba(250, 255, 255, 0.02) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1%);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

menu {
  background: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  margin-inline: auto;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  width: 65%;
  left: 20%;
  padding: 1.4em;
}

nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #CBD5DF;
  font-weight: bolder;
  position: relative;
}

nav li a::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background-color: #535792;
  height: 4px;
  width: 0%;
  top: 25px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

nav li a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

nav li a:hover {
  color: #C4C7C8;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="assests/images/moon.png" alt="" />

  <menu>
    <li><a class="list-item" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="list-item" href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a class="list-item" href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a class="list-item" href="#">C.V</a></li>
    <li><a class="list-item" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </menu>
</nav>

<button id="toggle_navBar">Toggle NavBar</button>
```

A few changes I made were for semantic reasons. You should use semantic tags if possible and have accessibility in mind. Accessibility is also part of SEO-ratings!

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic idea would be to have a button toggle some variable and then update the UI according to the value of that variable.

You can do this in several ways, but here is an example of a simple way to do it:

```js
// Get your toggle button element
const toggle = document.querySelector(".nav-toggle");
// Get your nav element
const nav = document.querySelector(".nav");

// Create a variable to hold the state of your nav
let navIsOpen = false;

// Listen for clicks on your nav toggle button
toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Update the nav state variable
  navIsOpen = !navIsOpen;
  // run a function that will update the nav "styles"
  updateNav();
})

// This function will update the UI state according to the value of the navIsOpen variable. Here you can update all things you need, like your navbar, your toggle button, ...
function updateNav() {
  navIsOpen
    ?
    nav.classList.add('nav--is-open') :
    nav.classList.remove('nav--is-open');
}
```

```css
.nav {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.nav--is-open {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="nav-toggle">Toggle nav</button>

<nav class="nav">
  Your nav here
</nav>
```

Comment: why so complicated? You do so many workarounds instead of simply using JS's `toggle` function. With that, you don't need a variable to "hold the state" or any if/else or ternary conditions.

Comment: Sure, that works fine too. Having a variable enables you to keep all elements "in sync" and to have a bit more control. this was just an example, you can change it t better feet your needs :)

Comment: If you want to keep it synced, it would be more redundant and easier to use the `contain` function. It will read out what actually is applied currently not what a variable contains that might got a false entry.

Comment: @tacoshy i don't think it is. That would be much more expensive to perform. Having a state variable decouples the state and the UI. It is nice to have the UI react to changes on the state, instead of making imperativ changes